# Django REST Framework page_size per view is not working as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**

The DRF settings are

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'tools.rest_framework.pagination.StandardResultsPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
}
```

Where the pagination class is customised to remove the URL for next and previous page and use page number instead.

```
class StandardResultsPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        return self.page.next_page_number()

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        return self.page.previous_page_number()
```

I have two views where I want to customise the number of records per page

```
class DataCreateListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = 20


class DataMinimalListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataMinimalSerializer
    pagination.PageNumberPagination.page_size = 5
```

and URLs defined are

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('data/minimal/', views.DataMinimalListView.as_view()),
  path('data/', views.DataCreateListView.as_view())
]
```

But when I visit the path

```
https://example.com/data/
```

It gives only 5 records instead of 20.

But when I remove the `page_size` from the `DataMinimalListView` then it gives 20.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the `PageNumberPagination.page_size` got the **`5`** as the ***last value*** during the ***server start-up***. That is, the pagination class will use the *last received value* for the `page_size` across the *current module*

IMO, setting the ***`.page_size`*** attribute on the view class isn't an elegant solution. Set the **`page_size_query_param`** attribute of the pagination class.

```
class StandardResultsPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'size'  # items per page

    def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        return self.page.next_page_number()

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        return self.page.previous_page_number()
```

Then you can control the items per page by using **`size`** query parameter as

```
https://example.com/data/?size=10
```